# ‘Failure delivering result ResultInfo’ once then works normally after crash

Tags: java, android, exception, android-fileprovider, android-7.0-nougat

I had to update my app to work along with the new android versions, targeting the N version, I Updated:

from:

Uri.fromFile();

to:

FileProvider.getUriForFile();

I did this as follows:

Based on: ( [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed) )

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities=" com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

FntTakePicture:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//......
//......

btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {


            outputFileName = null;
            try {

                /*if(fragmentPosition == 0 || fragmentPosition == 4)
                    outputFileName = Images.createImageFile2();//PNG
                else
                    outputFileName = Images.createImageFile3();//JPG*/

                outputFileName = Images.createImageFile3();

                //takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(outputFileName));
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),"com.mydomain.fileprovider",outputFileName);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RC_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                FirebaseCrash.report(e);
            }

        }
    }
});

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RC_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        loadImage(outputFileName.getAbsolutePath());//outputFileName.getAbsolutePath()

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            txtInstructions.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                    String.format(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.validate_picture2),
                            defaultValidateText
                    ),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
            ));

        } else {
            txtInstructions.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                    String.format(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.validate_picture2),
                            defaultValidateText
                    )), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }

        btnTakePicture.setText(getString(R.string.take_photo_again));
        //this.data.setImage(Images.compressImage(picture),fragmentPosition);
        this.data.setImage(outputFileName.getAbsolutePath(),fragmentPosition);
        Log.e("Data Picture"," Vin: "+this.data.getVin()+" lon: "+this.data.getLon()+ " lat: "+this.data.getLat());


        if(lastPage)
        validateContinueBoton();
        listener.save(this.data);
    }
}

public void loadImage(final String path){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>(){

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return Images.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(path,
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ancho_default)/2);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imgPictureTaken.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imgPictureTaken.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }.execute(null,null,null);
}
```

Images Class:

```
public class Images{


    static File createImageFile3() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "NTS_Image_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(App.getContext())[0];

        File nf = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  // prefix
                ".jpg",         // suffix
                storageDir      // directory
        );

        nf.deleteOnExit();
        return nf;
    }
}
```

Also, this event is in a fragment, I don't know if that's matters.

After run install app give it permissions then crash once it works normally…

The exception I got it this:

04-17 15:00:10.058 669-669/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
04-17 15:00:10.202 13596-13596/com.mydomain E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.mydomain, PID: 13596
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=74538, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.mydomain/com.mydomain.CaptureWizard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4094)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.mydomain.FntTakePicture.onActivityResult(FntTakePicture.java:201)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
                                                                           at com.mydomain.CaptureWizard.onActivityResult(CaptureWizard.java:133)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6931)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference at com.mydomain.FntTakePicture.onActivityResult(FntTakePicture.java:201)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are saving `outputFileName` in your saved instance state `Bundle`. Your process may be terminated while your app is in the background, which would cause that field to become `null` by default in your new process.